# xcode 7.2 Could not build Objective-C module

Tags: ios, xcode, module, xcodebuild

I have just updated my Xcode to version 7.2. Now I try to build a [framework](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) from command line using xcodebuild but have this error

```
.... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CAMediaTiming.h:6:9: note: in file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CAMediaTiming.h:6:
#import <QuartzCore/CABase.h>
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CABase.h:11:10: error: could not build module 'Darwin'
#include <stdbool.h>
         ^
/Users/atran/Desktop/Repos/DSA_Working_Directory/Libs/Kingfisher/Kingfisher/Kingfisher.h:27:9: note: while building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/atran/Desktop/Repos/DSA_Working_Directory/Libs/Kingfisher/Kingfisher/Kingfisher.h:27:
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UICollectionViewLayout.h:11:9: note: while building module 'QuartzCore' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UICollectionViewLayout.h:11:
#import <QuartzCore/CATransform3D.h>
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CAEAGLLayer.h:7:9: note: while building module 'OpenGLES' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CAEAGLLayer.h:7:
#import <OpenGLES/EAGLDrawable.h>
        ^
<module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#import "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/Headers/EAGL.h"
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/Headers/EAGL.h:8:10: error: could not build module 'Foundation'
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>
         ^
<module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#import "/Users/atran/Desktop/Repos/DSA_Working_Directory/Libs/Kingfisher/Kingfisher/Kingfisher.h"
        ^
/Users/atran/Desktop/Repos/DSA_Working_Directory/Libs/Kingfisher/Kingfisher/Kingfisher.h:27:9: error: could not build module 'UIKit'
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
        ^
<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'Kingfisher'
```

Everything worked well in XCode 7.1. so there must be something changed in XCode 7.2. Anyone has a clue?

Edit:

this is my build commmand

This works

```
xcodebuild clean build -workspace XYZ.xcworkspace -scheme ABC -configuration Debug -sdk iphoneos
```

This doesn't work:

```
xcodebuild clean build -workspace XYZ.xcworkspace -scheme ABC -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator
```

Comment: tried build clean, delete derived data folder and rebuild?

Comment: that was the first thing I tried and it didn't work.

Comment: i am having the same problem and nothing. If someone finds out something please share.

Comment: What are the command line parameters you're using? I'm seeing a similar issue here and I believe it has to to with `-sdk iphonesimulator` not being fully respected, it looks like it's trying to use that SDK but it's outputting to the wrong intermediary build folder, in my case if I use `-showBuildSettings` as well I can see it although the settings say it should go to `Debug-iphonesimulator`, it actually tries to put the binaries into the `Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos` folder instead.

Comment: I edited my question to show the commands I used.

Comment: Asked in apple forum too: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/27975

Comment: Another bug on same issue - https://openradar.appspot.com/23857648

Comment: Post on Apple's list as well: https://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2015/Dec/msg00036.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One possible workaround would be to supply a destination by adding the following:

```
-destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6'
```

In your case this would like this:

`xcodebuild clean build -workspace XYZ.xcworkspace \
-scheme ABC -configuration Debug \
-sdk iphonesimulator \
-destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6'`

Comment: Yes! THank you! Can you explain, why it's required?

Comment: The destination used to be picked by the command line tools automatically, not anymore

Answer (score 2):

Try to specify the destination, i.e, `xcodebuild -workspace 'App.xcworkspace' -scheme 'App Scheme' -destination 'id=[THE_SIMULATOR_ID_YOU_WISH_TO_USE]' -sdk iphonesimulator9.2 -configuration Debug`

Reference: https://twitter.com/nlutsenko/status/674863890342109185

Answer (score 0):

Alternative could be to use https://github.com/facebook/xctool
which works similar to xcodebuild

```
../<path>/xctool/xctool.sh clean build -workspace XYZ.xcworkspace -scheme ABC -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator
```

Answer (score 0):

I reported the same issue to Apple, it actually happens on any type of project when building from the command line using a "scheme" and specifying -sdk as simulator.

I looks like the `ARCH` and `PLATFORM_NAME` variables are incorrectly set even though we're specifying `-sdk iphonesimulator`. My current work around is to specify `PLATFORM_NAME=iphonesimulator` on top of the `-sdk iphonesimulator` flag on my `xcodebuild` command line.

Waiting to hear more from my bug report to Apple.

Comment: I was thinking initially that my Xcode 7.2 installation is not proper. I did a Software update from AppStore. So even if we clean and re-install Xcode7.2  will not fix this issue right? Its clearly an issue in Xcode 7.2. Please confirm.

Comment: yeah, looks like an issue with the CLI Tools more specifically.