# "xcodebuild" command line is not working as expected in Xcode 7.2 with option "-arch"

Tags: xcodebuild, xcode7.2

The following command line will work perfectly with Xcode 7.1 and Xcode 7.1.1.

```
xcodebuild clean build -workspace MyProject.xcworkspace -scheme MyProject -sdk iphonesimulator9.2 -arch i386 -configuration Debug
```

But the above is not working in Xcode 7.2. Its always failed to link libraries with the following error. The issue is with the command line argument -arch.

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-clwvgmuubptcujfaauznutwgzbbz/Build/Intermediates/Extensions.build/Debug/Extensions.build/Objects-normal/i386/NSString+Convenience.o /Users/<user>/Documents/workspace/depot/builds/<build_id>/Client/iOS/Platform/Text/Common/NSString/NSString+Convenience.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
```

If I am not using "-arch" and using "destination" it works. For example the following command line option will work in Xcode 7.2

```
xcodebuild clean build -workspace MyProject.xcworkspace -scheme MyProject -sdk iphonesimulator9.2 -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6' -configuration Debug
```

Any idea why this issue in Xcode 7.2? Or its may be an issue in my project. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xcode 7.2 Could not build Objective-C module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34180163/xcode-7-2-could-not-build-objective-c-module)