# Building project using xcodebuild fails with Xcode 7.2

Tags: ios, xcode7, xcodebuild

I just moved to Xcode 7.2 and am trying to compile a dynamic framework using `xcodebuild` and `lipo`

```
xcodebuild -project ProjectName.xcodeproj -scheme ProjectName -sdk iphonesimulator
```

This command fails with strange errors like `Unsupported architecture` (in frameworks like CoreText). The issue has also been [discussed here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/27975) but I don't see a solution which would work. Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xcode 7.2 Could not build Objective-C module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34180163/xcode-7-2-could-not-build-objective-c-module)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to [a bug](https://openradar.appspot.com/23857648) in Xcode 7.2 (and 7.2.1).

A workaround suggestion has been provided in the supplied link since this question was asked. To sum up, you can add the parameter `PLATFORM_NAME=iphonesimulator`, and then it magically works. For example:

```
xcodebuild -project ProjectName.xcodeproj -scheme ProjectName -sdk iphonesimulator -arch i386 PLATFORM_NAME=iphonesimulator build
```

See also my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22328882#34591441) (where there is also another suggestion for a workaround)