# 'Could not built Objective-C module' for C static library in iOS Framework when module uncached

Tags: ios, c, swift, xcode, carthage

I have a Swift framework that comprises a C static library. That framework is used in an iOS app.
If I do a `carthage archive` of my framework, then bring the output into my app in a separate Xcode project, then when it tries to compile the app it barfs during a `CompileSwift` command:

```
<module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#import "my_sdk.h"
    ^
/Users/myUser/my-swift-sdk/ext/my-c-sdk/include/c_sdk.h:10:10: note: in file included from /Users/myUser/my-swift-sdk/ext/my-c-sdk/include/c_sdk.h:10:
#include "alpha/alpha.h"
     ^
/Users/myUser/my-swift-sdk/ext/my-c-sdk/include/alpha/alpha.h:12:10: note: in file included from /Users/myUser/my-swift-sdk/ext/my-c-sdk/include/alpha/alpha.h:12:
 #include "../bravo/bravo.h"
     ^
/Users/myUser/my-swift-sdk/ext/my-c-sdk/include/alpha/../bravo/bravo.h:13:10: error: 'omega.h' file not found
#include "omega.h"
     ^
<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'libMyCSdk'
0  swift                    0x000000010680664a PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 42
1  swift                    0x0000000106805dfe SignalHandler(int) + 302
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff60ee7b3d _sigtramp + 29
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x0000000100020812 _sigtramp + 2668858610
4  swift                    0x0000000103f7a197 swift::GenericSignatureBuilder::addRequirement(swift::Requirement const&, swift::GenericSignatureBuilder::FloatingRequirementSource, swift::ModuleDecl*) + 887
5  swift                    0x0000000104005922 substType(swift::Type, llvm::function_ref<swift::Type (swift::SubstitutableType*)>, llvm::function_ref<llvm::Optional<swift::ProtocolConformanceRef> (swift::CanType, swift::Type, swift::ProtocolType*)>, swift::SubstOptions) + 2882
6  swift                    0x0000000104011318 swift::TypeBase::getTypeOfMember(swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::ValueDecl const*, swift::Type) + 168
7  swift                    0x0000000103b01582 swift::CalleeCandidateInfo::CalleeCandidateInfo(swift::Type, llvm::ArrayRef<swift::constraints::OverloadChoice>, bool, swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem&, bool) + 1122
8  swift                    0x0000000103a90b2c (anonymous namespace)::FailureDiagnosis::visitApplyExpr(swift::ApplyExpr*) + 10828
9  swift                    0x0000000103a6e206 swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem::diagnoseFailureForExpr(swift::Expr*) + 70
10 swift                    0x0000000103aa15af swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem::salvage(llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::constraints::Solution>&, swift::Expr*) + 6207
11 swift                    0x0000000103ba644a swift::TypeChecker::solveForExpression(swift::Expr*&, swift::DeclContext*, swift::Type, swift::FreeTypeVariableBinding, swift::ExprTypeCheckListener*, swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem&, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::constraints::Solution>&, swift::OptionSet<swift::TypeCheckExprFlags, unsigned int>) + 122
12 swift                    0x0000000103ba6b27 swift::TypeChecker::typeCheckExpression(swift::Expr*&, swift::DeclContext*, swift::TypeLoc, swift::ContextualTypePurpose, swift::OptionSet<swift::TypeCheckExprFlags, unsigned int>, swift::ExprTypeCheckListener*, swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem*) + 1207
13 swift                    0x0000000103a7ee5c (anonymous namespace)::FailureDiagnosis::typeCheckChildIndependently(swift::Expr*, swift::Type, swift::ContextualTypePurpose, swift::OptionSet<TCCFlags, unsigned int>, swift::ExprTypeCheckListener*, bool) + 1516
14 swift                    0x0000000103a76a40 swift::ASTVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::FailureDiagnosis, bool, void, void, void, void, void>::visit(swift::Expr*) + 25280
15 swift                    0x0000000103a6e206 swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem::diagnoseFailureForExpr(swift::Expr*) + 70
16 swift                    0x0000000103aa15af swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem::salvage(llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::constraints::Solution>&, swift::Expr*) + 6207
17 swift                    0x0000000103ba644a swift::TypeChecker::solveForExpression(swift::Expr*&, swift::DeclContext*, swift::Type, swift::FreeTypeVariableBinding, swift::ExprTypeCheckListener*, swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem&, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::constraints::Solution>&, swift::OptionSet<swift::TypeCheckExprFlags, unsigned int>) + 122
18 swift                    0x0000000103ba6b27 swift::TypeChecker::typeCheckExpression(swift::Expr*&, swift::DeclContext*, swift::TypeLoc, swift::ContextualTypePurpose, swift::OptionSet<swift::TypeCheckExprFlags, unsigned int>, swift::ExprTypeCheckListener*, swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem*) + 1207
19 swift                    0x0000000103c3e9ac swift::ASTVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::StmtChecker, void, swift::Stmt*, void, void, void, void>::visit(swift::Stmt*) + 12044
20 swift                    0x0000000103c3abbe swift::TypeChecker::typeCheckAbstractFunctionBodyUntil(swift::AbstractFunctionDecl*, swift::SourceLoc) + 1294
21 swift                    0x0000000103c40468 swift::TypeChecker::typeCheckAbstractFunctionBody(swift::AbstractFunctionDecl*) + 888
22 swift                    0x0000000103c67013 swift::performTypeChecking(swift::SourceFile&, swift::TopLevelContext&, swift::OptionSet<swift::TypeCheckingFlags, unsigned int>, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int) + 2515
23 swift                    0x00000001038a1865 swift::CompilerInstance::performSema() + 4949
24 swift                    0x0000000102a8e59b performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*, swift::UnifiedStatsReporter*) + 731
25 swift                    0x0000000102a8adc5 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 7717
26 swift                    0x0000000102a30a35 main + 1349
27 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff60cfe085 start + 1
Stack dump:
0.      Program arguments: [The stuff sent to SwiftCompile - lots to redact so will add if required]
1.      While type-checking 'addDevice()' at /Users/myUser/my-app/Sources/Views/MyView1/MyView1ViewController.swift:54:13
2.      While type-checking statement at [/Users/myUser/my-app/Sources/Views/MyView1/MyView1ViewController.swift:54:30 - line:94:5]
[code and some more 'While type-checking expression']
error: Segmentation fault: 11
```

I've had to redact it/change paths as it's not an open source project, but everything important should be there.

This does not happen if I compile the framework in Xcode then copy the resulting binary over to the Carthage directory in the app; the app builds fine. The frameworks are different sizes, but this is expected as Carthage will be creating a fat binary for the sim and device, whereas one generated by Xcode will only be doing one or the other.

I've tried getting Carthage to build and archive in Debug configuration; this does not work either (Debug would include having any optimisation/stripping off).

**Edit**: The iOS app that uses the framework only breaks on building for the simulator. If I build for the device, it's fine.

**Edit**: I've tried the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34180163/xcode-7-2-could-not-build-objective-c-module) about adding destination when using xcodebuild from the command line i.e. `xcodebuild clean build -scheme App -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 8'` - didn't work.

**Edit**: To state it explicitly, I've nuked DerivedData a few times too :)

**Edit**: Environment is Xcode 10.0, building with iOS 12 SDK on Mojave

**Edit**: Title changed to reflect new research. Carthage is a red herring. The problem is this:

- The App builds if the Module cache inside DerivedData contains an entry for the C static library (e.g. when it was built as part of building the Swift Framework.
- If DerivedData is cleared between building the Swift Framework and building the App, then the error scenario above occurs.
- Carthage was displaying the second behaviour because it builds using a separate DerivedData directory with its own Module cache, meaning that when trying to build the App, no module for the C library is in the cache that the App is using (the default one).
- For most linked frameworks with C or Objective-C modules, when building the App they get a cache entry in the Module cache. My C static library does not when building the App using the linked Framework. It does get an entry when building the Framework itself. It likely doesn't get one because xcodebuild fails to do whatever it needs to do to cache the module, because it encounters the 'missing' header above.

**Edit**: Some success! If I point 'Header Search Paths' at the include directories of my C static library, and rename the module.modulemap file there, it all compiles. This is not a solution, but confirms that the App project wants headers in order to create a cached version of the module.

Comment: The message at the bottom is a stack trace from when the Swift compiler crashed. You should file a bug report at bugreport.apple.com.

Answer (score 0):

How are your headers in the C project organized?

If they have this pattern:

```
Lib/
    Umbrella.h
    A/
        A1.h
        A2.h
    B/
        B1.h
        B2.h
```

Then you will need to do special header copy phases not just the normal ones because the relative paths to them matter in this case once copied into the framework.